# ¿Cómo retornar el id de una consulta con php y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buen día. Lo que requiero es hacer una consulta que se muestra en el primer bloque con el nombre de "$sqlconsulta" y al realizarla retornar el "idcompra" para así poder realizar finalmente el ingreso.

El primer bloque es de la función insertar y el segundo bloque son las funciones a las que se llaman en el primero.

```
public function insertar($idusuario,$rfc,$monto,$facturapdf,$facturaxml,$fechaticket,$fecharegistro,$UUID)
{      
    $sql="INSERT INTO ingresoarchivos (idusuario,rfc,monto,facturapdf,facturaxml,fechaticket,fecharegistro,UUID,estado)
    VALUES ('$idusuario','$rfc','$monto','$facturapdf','$facturaxml','$fechaticket','$fecharegistro','$UUID','Espera')";

    $idingresonew=ejecutarConsulta_retornarID($sql);
    $sw=true;

    $sqlconsulta="SELECT * FROM compra WHERE rfc='$rfc' AND total=$monto AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')=DATE_FORMAT('$fechaticket', '%d/%m/%Y')";

    $idcompra = ejecutarConsultaBuscaCompra($sqlconsulta);

    $sqlune="INSERT INTO compra_ingreso(idcompra,idingreso) VALUES ('$idcompra','$idingresonew')";
    ejecutarConsulta($sqlune) or $sw = false;

    return $sw;
}

function ejecutarConsulta($sql)
{
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($sql); 
    return $query;
}

function ejecutarConsultaBuscaCompra($sql)
{
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
    $campo = $query->fetch_array();
    return $campo['idcompra'];
}

function ejecutarConsulta_retornarID($sql)
{
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($sql);        
    return $conexion->insert_id;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias de usar un tipo CLASS:

```
class ClsInsertar {
    public $db;
    public $id;
    function _constructor(){
        // Aqui va tu proceso de conexion
        $this->db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    }
    function insertar($idusuario,$rfc,$monto,$facturapdf,$facturaxml,$fechaticket,$fecharegistro,$UUID){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ingresoarchivos
                    (idusuario,rfc,monto,facturapdf,facturaxml,fechaticket,fecharegistro,UUID,estado)
                VALUES
                    ('$idusuario','$rfc','$monto','$facturapdf','$facturaxml','$fechaticket','$fecharegistro','$UUID','Espera')";
        // Ejecutamos el SQL y obtenemos el ID
        $this->ejecutarConsulta($sql);
        $sw=($this->id != 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        //Busqueda
        $sqlconsulta="SELECT * FROM compra WHERE rfc='$rfc' AND total=$monto AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')=DATE_FORMAT('$fechaticket', '%d/%m/%Y')";
        $this->ejecutarConsultaBuscaCompra($sqlconsulta);
        //Insertar la compra
        $sqlune="INSERT INTO compra_ingreso(idcompra,idingreso) VALUES ('{$this->id}','$idingresonew')";
        $this->ejecutarConsulta($sqlune);
        return $sw;
    }
    function ejecutarConsulta(){
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $this->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
    function ejecutarConsultaBuscaCompra($sql){
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $campo = $query->fetch_array();
        return $campo['idcompra'];
    }
}
```

Comment: por que? que tiene que ver `Class` con retornar un id?

Comment: para lo que el requiere no es necesario involucrar POO

Comment: Es mas fácil, porque dentro de `class` se declara una variable publica `public $mi_variable` y las demás `function` pueden acceder a ellas directamente con `$this->mi_variable`.